# How to get original event object in action handler?

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I would like to clarify the ways to get original event object in action handler.

The [documentation](https://guides.emberjs.com/release/components/handling-events/) says:

> To utilize an `event` object as a function parameter:
>
> - Define the event handler in the component (which is designed to receive the browser event object).
> - Or, assign an action to an inline event handler in the template (which creates a closure action and does receive the event object as
>     an argument).

So to get an event object on inline handler we do like so:

*hbs:*

```
<form onsubmit={{action "submit"}}>
```

*js:*

```
actions: {
  submit(e) {
    console.log(e); // original event
  }
}
```

And what about the first option to define event handler in component?

Comment: Don't do the first option and your example is correct

Comment: @Lux Can you explain what exactly the first option is about? The documentation lacks the example of these two points. And why it shouldn't be used?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the `event handler in the component` means the function on the component that is called the event name. Its [literally the first example here](https://guides.emberjs.com/release/components/handling-events/). And as the documentation says:

> Simply implement the name of the event you want to respond to as a method on your component.

So when you call your component like this:

```
{{#double-clickable}}
  This is a double clickable area!
{{/double-clickable}}
```

and this is the `js` code for the component:

```
import Component from '@ember/component';

export default Component.extend({
  doubleClick(e) {
    alert('DoubleClickableComponent was clicked!');
    console.log('and this is the event', e);
  }
});
```

then the `doubleClick` function receives the event when the event is triggered on the corresponding tag.

However corresponding tags for components will go away in the long term. Have a look at the [Angle Bracket Invocation RFC](https://github.com/emberjs/rfcs/blob/master/text/0311-angle-bracket-invocation.md#tag-name) and the [Template only Components RFC](https://github.com/emberjs/rfcs/blob/master/text/0278-template-only-components.md). That concept is already completely removed from [glimmer](http://glimmerjs.com) components.

You still *can* use it and there maybe are rare use-cases when you still *have* to use it, but closure actions are definitely the way to go whenever possible!

So when you have this template:

```
<button onclick={{action 'myAction' 10}}>Click me</button>
```

and the corresponding `component.js`:

```
actions: {
  myAction(n, e) {
    console.log(n); // the number 10
    console.log(e); // event
  }
}
```

It should also be mentioned that [*Event handler methods in components will usually receive an instance of jquery.Event as an argument*](https://github.com/emberjs/rfcs/blob/master/text/0294-optional-jquery.md#introducing-ember-jquery-legacy-and-deprecating-jqueryevent-usage).
The referenced RFC explains detailed how this will change with the removal of `jQuery`.